# Pandas groupby ignoring certain row values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to group data based on a named row, where each one is a unique value.

Sample df

```
  Name            Description

'Apple'          'A Succulent Fruit'
'Bottom'         'Depending on the context body area'
'Jeans'          'A unisex clothing item'
'Boots'          'A type of show or a clothing item'
'Boots'          'A popular clothing item for the winder'
'Apple'          'some people name their children after this fruit'
```

Using this dataframe, I group by the unique name and assign its value in a new column called "type" byusing a regex pattern it extracts keywords from a keyword list.

```
keyword_list = ['Fruit','body area', 'clothing item']
```

Ideally It should return something like:

```
     Name         Type

    'Apple'      'Fruit'
    'Bottom'     'body area'
    'Jeans'      'clothing item'
    'Boots'      'clothing item'
```

This works fine normally however I'm running into a dataloss issue. The dataframe with all unique names is 933 x 1 ('Name' x 'Type'), however the dataframe being returned is 775 x 1 (and it should be the same size). Indicating that some rows are either ignored or not actually appended.

This is the current code I'm using:

```
keyword_list = ['Fruit','body area', 'clothing item']

ptn = r'\b(' + '|'.join(keyword_list) + r')\b'

test_df = df.set_index('Name').Desc.str.extractall(ptn).reset_index(level=1, drop=False)[0]

pre_shape = test_df.groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax(skipna=False)).to_frame('Type')

reshaped_df = pre_shape.pivot_table(index='Name', values='Type',
                                            aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(str(v) for v in x))

new_df = pd.merge(reshaped_df, odf, on=['Name'], how='inner') # 'odf' is another dataframe of size 933 x 1
```

The description column is not null for any of the unique values ('Name'), and they all have at least one of the keywords, so I'm not sure why its skipping some of these rows.

This is what I've tried:

```
new_df = pd.merge(reshaped_df, odf, on=['Name'], how='outer') # How set to 'outer'
```

This returns an equal sized df however the values that were missing are now just NaN.

```
test_df = df.set_index('Name').Desc.str.extractall(ptn).reset_index(level=1, drop=False)[0] # Drop set to 'False'
```

This has no effect.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: ```len(test_df.dropna())``` what do you get?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just got back in. This is eliminates rows, so the dataset becomes rectangular however at the cost of around 133 entities, which puts me back where I am sadly

Comment: That's my point. The fact you lose rows with my code (which just counts the number of rows with NaN) means that some of your rows do not contain an item on your key word list. My guess is your not accounting for capitalization, so if there is "Body area" or "Clothing Item" it wont match.

Comment: Actually, your test data further proves my point. ```'Apple'   'some people name their children after this fruit'``` will not match due to ```'fruit'``` been lower case, but it been ```'Fruit'``` in your keywords list. Change ```str.extractall(ptn)``` to ```str.extractall(ptn, flags = re.IGNORECASE)``` and your code will probably work fine.

Comment: `flags = re.IGNORECASE` this increased the discovery rate for already assigned values, but I'm still sitting at 803 out of 933. One thing I should note is that several of the keywords in my actual list are entity identifiers (i.e corp, inc, llc), so entities that don't have those on there are difficult to classify, but this is outside the question.

Comment: I should also note that capitalization, and relevant punctuation had been removed prior.

Comment: Unfortunately without using your actual dataset, I can't really debug more than I have, but your error is definitely in this extract step.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `str.findall` with `mode`

```
df['Type']=df.Description.str.findall('|'.join(keyword_list))
s = df.groupby('Name')['Type'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x.sum())[0]).reset_index()
s
Out[49]: 
     Name           Type
0   Apple          Fruit
1   Boots  clothing item
2  Bottom      body area
3   Jeans  clothing item
```

Comment: wouldnt that be the same as `df.set_index('Name').Desc.str.extractall(ptn).reset_index(level=1, drop=False)[0]`?

Comment: @SebastianGoslin what is your expected output ? so one line may have two key words ?

Comment: The 3rd line of the code is supposed to aggregate each occurrence in 'Desc' and assign type based on the highest frequency keyword, so if 'clothing item' appears 3 times in a `Desc` then its type is 'clothing item'. My bad for not mentioning that I'll update the post.

Comment: @SebastianGoslin i got you , check the update . I am adding the couple of Fruit at the end of last row in Description, so after mode , it should output Fruit , since that is most freq words

Comment: This works however, since its output is a list I'd need to map it to the other dataframe in the post (odf) based on the key which is 'Name' in this case. Hence the merge. I can try mapping the list, but it seems a bit cumbersome compared to just merging

Comment: Gotcha trying it now, right now I'm getting `IndexError: index out of bounds`

Comment: @SebastianGoslin update again , try the code with groupby

Comment: still getting an index error. I took out the merge and the error persists. I also took out the previous groupby (`pre_shape`) with no luck.

Comment: @SebastianGoslin you may check what is the different between your sample data and your real data , since if you running above with your sample data , you should get the expected output .

Comment: gotcha, the sample data works great, I just adjusted to make sure nothing is undefined, the index error went away which is a good sign, however I'm getting this now: `pandas.errors.AbstractMethodError: This method must be defined in the concrete class SeriesGroupBy`

Comment: @SebastianGoslin what is your pandas version ?

Comment: as of now 0.24.2, looking the error up it seems to be an issue with python 2.7 and back.

Comment: @SebastianGoslin so if  above code works fine with the sample your provided , however , failed in your real dfs, then you need to find the different between them , without seeing the whole data , I can not help